# Ng Select dropdown with condition

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular8, angular-ngselect

I need to display the **purchaseOrderStatusName** in a **NgSelect dropdown**. In **API** different status values are available such as: **OPEN,RECEIVED,CANCELLED**.

**TS file:**

```
  getAllPurchaseOrders() {
    this.purchaseOrderService.getAllPurchaseOrders().subscribe(
      data => { this.formModel.schema.purchaseOrders['purchaseOrders'] = data; 
    });
  }
```

**Ng-Select Drop Down:**

```
<ng-select [items]=" formModel.schema.purchaseOrders['purchaseOrders']" bindLabel="referenceNumber" 
bindValue="id" placeholder="Select PO" clearAllText="Clear" formControlName="purchaseOrderId">

   <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
      <span [ngOptionHighlight]="search">
          {{ item.referenceNumber +'-'+ item.purchaseOrderStatusName}}
     </span>
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm" let-index="index">
      <span [ngOptionHighlight]="search">
          {{ item.referenceNumber +'-'+ item.purchaseOrderStatusName}}
      </span>
   </ng-template>

</ng-select>
```

I got all values in **formModel.schema.purchaseOrders['purchaseOrders']**. Now all Reference Number is displaying.

**Question:-**

Now how to display the **referenceNumber** where the **purchaseOrderStatusName= "OPEN"**

Instead of giving condition in NgSelect dropdown, is there any way to give a condition in get method itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for.

Show only the `referenceNumber` when `purchaseOrderStatus` is **OPEN** and both reference number and status name when `purchaseOrderStatus` is **RECEIVED** or **CANCELLED**.

**Updated answer based on OP comment**

A new field label can be added in the data whose value will be set based on the required condition.

**TS file**:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

getAllPurchaseOrders() {
  this.purchaseOrderService.getAllPurchaseOrders()
  pipe(
    map(data => {
      data.label =
        data.purchaseOrderStatusName !== 'OPEN'
          ? data.referenceNumber + '-' + data.purchaseOrderStatusName
          : data.referenceNumber;
    })
  )
  .subscribe(
    data => { this.formModel.schema.purchaseOrders['purchaseOrders'] = data;
  });
}
```

**Ng-Select Drop Down**:

```
<span [ngOptionHighlight]="search">
    {{ item.label }}
</span>
```

---

**Previous Answer**:

Condition given inside ngSelect dropdown without manipulating data

**One line approach** -

```
<span [ngOptionHighlight]="search">
    {{ item.referenceNumber }} {{ item.purchaseOrderStatusName !== 'OPEN' ? '-' + item.purchaseOrderStatusName : '' }}
</span>
```

**Multiple line approach** -

```
<span *ngIf="item.purchaseOrderStatusName !== 'OPEN'" [ngOptionHighlight]="search">
  {{ item.referenceNumber +'-'+ item.purchaseOrderStatusName }}
</span>
<span *ngIf="item.purchaseOrderStatusName === 'OPEN'" [ngOptionHighlight]="search">
  {{ item.referenceNumber }}
</span>
```

Comment: Instead of giving condition in NgSelect dropdown , is there any way to give a condition in get method(ts file) itself??

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this , by making use `ng-container`

```
  <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm" let-index="index">
      <span [ngOptionHighlight]="search">
        <ng-container *ngIf="item.purchaseOrderStatusName==='OPEN'">
          {{ item.referenceNumber}}
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="item.purchaseOrderStatusName!=='OPEN'">
          {{ item.referenceNumber +'-'+ item.purchaseOrderStatusName}}
        </ng-container>
      </span>
   </ng-template>
```

Comment: Instead of giving condition in NgSelect dropdown , is there any way to give a condition in get method itself??

Comment: @AngelReji- you can create getmethod in ts file and call it from html , for that replace condition line with the get method you create